# Matlab: Random Number depending on another

Tags: matlab, random, dependencies, intervals

I need your help with my Matlab code...

I want to set a random Number (between 0 and 1) in a loop:

```
 for i=1:20
m1(i)= rand;
```

and a second random number (n1(i) should be set depending on the first max 0.2 greater/smaller but at least 0.1 greater/smaller than m1(i) without negative values.

So in the end I want two vectors with numbers between 0 and 1, but element 1 in m1 and element 1 in n1 shouldn't be too different but also not too close to another...

Would be so thankful for your tips, I don't get it...

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
for i=1:20
    m1(i)=rand;
    a=.2;% desired range
    n1(i) = (m1(i)-a).*rand(1,1) + m1(i)/2; % creating the second random vector 
  end
```

Comment: Close, but `n1-.2 < m1 && n1-.1 > m1` is not satisfied

Comment: Well thank you both, but this doesn't work... There was e.g. 0.96xx and 0.5xx.. Any other idea? I am really confused..

Comment: Now that I think about it, there are certain conditions in which you can never find n1. For example, if m1=.99, then it is impossible to find n1 that satisfies the conditions. The same goes for m1=.001. I think the original question needs modification.

Comment: If m1 == .99, n1 can be between [.79,.89]. It's not the same distribution as m (n will have a smaller tail)  but it is a random number.

Answer (score 0):

```
N = 100;
m = rand(N,1); %random numbers in [0 1]
n1 = rand(N,1); %random numbers in [0 1]
%now we want to change the range of n from [0 1] to [m+0.1 m+0.2]
n1 = n1*0.1; %random numbers in [0 0.1]
n1 = n1+m+0.1; %random numbers in [m+0.1 m+0.2]

%to get a range [m-0.2 m-0.1]
n2 = rand(N,1); %random numbers in [0 1]
n2 = n2*0.1; %random numbers in [0 0.1]
n2 = n2-0.2+m; 

%but if n2 is negative we should have n1
n2(n2<0) = n1(n2<0);

%random put half the indexes as n1
[~,idx] = sort(rand(N,1));
n2(idx(1:floor(N/2)))=n1(idx(1:floor(N/2)));
```

n2 is your vector.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a couple of solutions and this was the first *complete* one I've come up with. Fits all the following constraints

- `.1 < |m-n| < .2`
- `0 < m < 1`
- `0 < n < 1`

My while loop isn't efficient, it was cleaner and easier to implement than constraining n(i) by [0,1]; it also maintains a random distribution. Just so you are aware, a `0 < n < 1` constraint will skew `n` towards .5 relative to `m`

```
ub = .2;
lb = .1;

for i = 1:1000
  m(i) = rand;


  n(i) = -1;
  % Determine n with [0,1] constraints
  while(n(i)<0 || n(i)>1)    
    n(i) = 2*(ub-lb)*rand + m(i)-(ub-lb);     % Determine the upper bound shell
    n(i) = n(i) + sign(n(i)-m(i))*lb;      % Add the lower bound
  end
  y(i) = m(i) - n(i);                    % Check the difference

end


figure;
hist(y,100);
```

[image: m-n]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a linearized solution:

```
len = 10000;                  %length of your vector
m1  = rand(len,1);            %input vector
g = (randi([0,1],len,1)*2-1); %random [-1 or 1] generator
a = 0.1.*m1.*g+m1;            %use a = 0.1.*g+m1 for an absolute [0.1,0.2] interval
b = 0.2.*m1.*g+m1;            %use b = 0.2.*g+m1 for an absolute [0.1,0.2] interval
n1 = a + (b-a).*rand(len,1);  %output vector
```